# Notepad++ how to only keep lines with certain format

Tags: notepad++

I have large text file, with much text inside it.

Every line has different text, or format.

I need to keep lines with certain format "text1:text2" and discard the rest.

For example, I have 9 lines:

1. 91.216.3.125:8085
2. 141.101.132.98:8085
3. Text messaging, or texting, is the act of composing and sending
4. asd1:bbc2
5. qedrt2:b32sv
6. electronic messages, typic
7. Short Message Service (SMS). I
8. yugiias:tugida2
9. nhcgdw:idwune

I need only 4, 5, 8, 9 lines to save, everything else has to be deleted.

Desired output:

1. asd1:bbc2
2. qedrt2:b32sv
3. yugiias:tugida2
4. nhcgdw:idwune

Comment: What I normally do is find things that don't match and replace them with nothing.  So you could match `^[^:]*\r\n` and replace it with nothing.  That deletes the lines that don't have a colon.  Then find `^.*\..*\r\n` and replace it with nothing to get rid of anything that contains a dot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I delete everything that is not matched by a pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20859891/how-can-i-delete-everything-that-is-not-matched-by-a-pattern)

Answer (score 0):

The following regular expression finds the lines that match your desired lines. Assuming your example input is representative you don't need to get more complex than this:

```
([a-z].*):(.*)
```

You can find all the lines you want and copy them out to another file. If there are only a smallish number of matching lines amongst the 'many' lines in the original file this is time effective as compared to trying to build and run a more complex answer.

Is that a workable answer? Or do you want to write a script to do it? Any preference for a language you want the script in?

There a large number of ways to achieve what you seem to want so you may need to supply some more constraints and/or expectations for people to help you more effectively.

Comment: Doesn't your regex match the ip addresses too?  Or am I confused?

Comment: @Jerry-Jeremiah : You are totally right. Missed it completely. Thanks so much for catching my blunder. New (edited) regex should do a little better.